# Why is this "no string attribute" error occurring when attempting to update account_type

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to add a method to update my acct_type, but I keep getting an error when trying to print out the new account.
class BankAccount(object):

```
def __init__(self, acct_holder, acct_type, balance = 0):
    self.holder = acct_holder
    self.type = acct_type
    self.balance = balance
    """
    Write a constructor for a bank account below.
    The following attributes:
    acct_holder will be a Person object
    acct_type is a string
    balance should be defaulted to 0 if not provided to the constructor, is an int
    """
    pass

def changeAccountType(self, newType):
    self.type = str(self.newType)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.holder) + self.type + str(self.balance)









account_1 = BankAccount('James','checking',45)
account_1.type.changeAccountType("dookieball_account")

print(account_1)
```

Comment: You call `changeAccountType` on **the `.type` itself**?

Comment: This is the error I get when I don't do that.     "self.type = str(self.newType)
AttributeError: 'BankAccount' object has no attribute 'newType'"

Comment: That is when I run account_1.changeAccountType("some_account")

Comment: wel you need to rewrite it to `self.type = str(newType)` so without the second `self`.

Comment: That worked great! I am confuse know though. Used another method on another class where I wanted to have a method that would raise an employees pay by a set amount, say 4%. The code looked like this

Comment: def raise_pay(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay*1.04)

Answer (score 1):

From your code above, I removed the ".type" from "account_1.type.changeAccountType..." and also removed "self." from "self.newType" in your changeaccount function.  newType is not contained in self.  Hope this help, it's my first attempt on here!

Answer (score 0):

```
account_1.type.changeAccountType("dookieball_account")
```

needs to be

```
account_1.changeAccountType("dookieball_account")
```

When you use .type, you are getting the type of account_1, which is a string, and trying to call the changeAccountType function on it. Removing it instead calls the function on account_1.

Also, change

```
self.type = str(self.newType)
```

to

```
self.type = str(newType)
```

Because the newType is a parameter of that function, it is not yet under self.